# ¿Cómo acceder desde un método a objetos generados dinámicamente dentro de otro método?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, alcance

Dentro de unos paneles van a haber una serie de datos, y un botón con la opción de borrar el panel respectivo con la información...
El problema es que estoy creando este botón de eliminar panel de forma dinámica, y no tengo forma de acceder a él por que se crea el objeto panel dentro de un método, es decir, si llamo al `panelInfo` desde un método `eliminarVenta()` que es externo a `crearVenta()`que es donode fue creado inicialmente, me salta el error de que no existe en el contexto actual.

```
  private void crearVenta()
    {
        Panel panelInfo= new Panel();
        panelInfo.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        panelInfo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(765, 74);
        panelInfo.Name = $"panelInfo_{count}";
        MessageBox.Show(panelInfo.Name);
        pan_principal.Controls.Add(panelInfo);
        panelInfo.BringToFront();

        count++;

    } 

 private void elimnarVenta()
    {
        panelInfo
    }

    private void btn_AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        crearVenta();
    }
```

[image: Los paneles creados dinámicamente están en el lado derecho, y dentro de ellos se ven los botones para eliminar el propio panel al que pertenecen]

Hay alguna forma en la que yo pueda acceder desde un método a objetos generados dinámicamente dentro de otro método, además como ponerles el evento `click` a todos ellos?
Le encuentran otra forma de hacerlo?

---

Estoy usando *Linq* como me sugeriste y me aparece este error "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto" así lo organicé

```
 private void ElimnarPanel(string panel)
        {
            var deletePanel = this.Controls.OfType<Panel>().
                                      Where(c => c.Name == panel).
                                      FirstOrDefault();

            deletePanel.Visible = false;
        }


        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ElimnarPanel("panel1");
        }
```

Comment: Resolviste el problema?

Comment: Estoy avanzando, ya está encontrando los paneles, le cambié el `this` por el nombre del panel que tenía de hijos a los paneles que se creaban dinámicamente, me falta es asignarle el evento click a todos los botones generados, que identifiquen el panel padre al que pertenecen y eliminarlo

Comment: Es que no me habias dicho q los paneles se creaban dentro de otro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer un método que recorra todos los paneles que hay en tu formulario usando **Linq** y pasándole como parámetro al método el nombre del panel que deseas eliminar:

```
private void ElimnarPanel(string panel)
{
    var panel = this.Controls.OfType<Panel>().
                              Where(c => c.Name == panel).
                              FirstOrDefault();

   //Una vez que obtienes el panel deseado pues haces con el lo que desees
   //Ej panel.Visible = false;
}
```

Para poder usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Se mas explicito, en donde te da ese error?

Comment: Cuando selecciono el panel, o creo seleccionarlo, doy la instrucción de que no sea visible de esta forma `deletePanel.Visible = false;`, y es cuando me salta error "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que en un foreach  aqui agregas tambien la funcionalidad click.

```
    private void Ocultar(string NombrePanel) 
    {
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
           
            if (item.Name== NombrePanel)
            {
                item.Visible = false;
                item.Click += Metodo_Click;

            }
        }
    }

    private void Metodo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //funcion del click
    }
```

Comment: Por cierto , en caso de que sean muchos paneles o controles  dinamicos , agregaría los paneles a una lista y los agregaría y removeria del forma principal, en lugar de ocultarlos  esto también hace que el foreach sea mas rapido al solo recorrer los paneles y no todos los controles